# Tensorflow input pipeline with rank 3 tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I just started to learn Tensorflow. Most projects I have been working on is using csv dataset to predict values with CNN architecture. Actually, I just use the example code from [Basic regression: Predict fuel efficiency](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression)

However, the current project I am working on has an input data structure like a 3D tensor. I tried to modify the input size within my hidden layer. Nevertheless, I did not get the outcomes.
My code is here (The first part of code is from [Tensorflow input pipeline where multiple rows correspond to a single observation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899526/tensorflow-input-pipeline-where-multiple-rows-correspond-to-a-single-observation), he had same situation as I have.)

```
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset('Batch training test/3+1testdata.csv')

# Skip the header line.
dataset = dataset.skip(1)

# Combine 6 lines into a single observation.
dataset = dataset.batch(6)

def parse_observation(line_batch):
    record_defaults = [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0]]
    a, b, c, d = tf.io.decode_csv(line_batch, record_defaults=record_defaults)
    features = tf.stack([a, b, c])
    label = d[-1]  # Take the label from the last row.
    return features, label

# Parse each observation into a `row_per_ob X 2` matrix of features and a
# scalar label.
dataset = dataset.map(parse_observation)

# Batch multiple observations.
dataset = dataset.batch(10)

# Optionally add a prefetch for performance.
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)

def build_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform',input_shape=(None,3,6)),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'),
    layers.Dense(1, kernel_initializer='he_uniform')
  ])

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=0.001)
  #optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

    model.compile(loss='mae',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mae', 'mse', 'msle'])
    return model


model = build_model()
history = model.fit(
  dataset,
  epochs=200)
```

What I expect is this machine using column data a,b,c to predict d[-1], instead the machine seems predicting d[-1] three times with input columns a,b,c individually. I know the problem comes from input shape, but how do I change it? Do I have to add convolutional 2d or padding layers?

I really have no clue for this, looking for someone's brilliant advices. Thank in advance!

Comment: The issue comes from your data pipeline but that is as much as I know. To debug this, I recommend printing out the data set shape after every consecutive method so that you know what is the shape of the data you are feeding your model. I would first check the parsing method. So, do `print(dataset)` after `dataset.map(parse_observation)`.

Comment: @RichardX after this step I got <MapDataset shapes: ((3, None), ()), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>. Then after final data input pipeline I got <PrefetchDataset shapes: ((None, 3, None), (None,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>. However, if I put (3,None) in the input_shape, it returns ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`. Any suggestion for that?

Comment: That's strange. If each example contains three scalars, then the output shape should be (3,) or (3, 1) for the first step. I wonder why it is None. I recommend taking an example from your data set at each step and printing its shape to debug what the None dimensions mean. Note that after a batch step, the first dimensions of each output will be None.